# How can I make a user control extend a class that extends UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance

I want to attempt an MVC design for my little app.

I have a normal Csharp class ViewBase which extends UserControl. It's a single .cs file.

I have multiple classes that I want to extend ViewBase. These are actual UserControls so they have a code behind .cs file and a .xaml file.

However, CSharp tells me that for these classes, their base class "differs from declared in other parts".

Is what I want to do possible at all? What am I doing wrong?

Note that I did not modify my XAML files, so they still use  tags.

Here is the relevant code:

```
// This gives the error in question and ViewBase is underlined
// "Base class of LoginView differs from declared in other parts"
public partial class LoginView : ViewBase {
    public LoginView(Shell shell, ControllerBase controller) : base(shell, controller) {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

// This one is a single .cs file
public abstract class ViewBase : UserControl {
    public Shell Shell { get; set; }
    public ControllerBase Controller { get; set; }

    protected ViewBase(Shell shell, ControllerBase controller)
    {
        Shell = shell;
        Controller = controller;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Note that I did not modify my XAML
>   files, so they still use tags

That's your problem. You'll need to change:

```
<UserControl ...>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

to

```
<local:ViewBase xmlns:local="clr-namespace:..."
    ...
</local:ViewBase>
```

The problem is you're telling the compiler you're inheriting `ViewBase` in one place (the *.cs* file) and `UserControl` in another (the *.xaml* file).

Comment: This needs a bit of elaboration